# Display visitor_posts facebook graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using visitor_post to display page visitor posts.
right now i can get created_time, message, and id in object. 
is it possible to display also the user profile picture?

Answer (score 0):

The `from` field holds the user id, and via Field Expansion syntax you can use that to request the `picture` property of that:

```
...?fields=from{picture.type(large)}
```

Be aware that you will need a page access token to make this request; with any other kind of token you won't get any user details for posts on pages any more.

That of course also means that you should only do this on the server side (which you should for caching purposes anyway), because a page access token should never be exposed in publicly available code such as client-side JavaScript.